# Validation for datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with validation in my project. I need to validate datetime when saving reservation.
It showing message "This date is reserved." but always create new reservation :(
It can be 3 identical datetime values and not more. Where I have problem in my code?

(I am learning RoR, so, please, be patient. :)

```
def create
    @reservation = Reservation.create!(reservation_params)
    @check_count = Reservation.select(:date).where('date = ?', @reservation.date).count
    if @check_count <= 3
        if @reservation.save!
            ReservationMailer.new_service(@reservation).deliver
            flash[:success] = "Successfully created reservation."
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    else
        flash[:error] = "This date is reserved."
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do

```
     @reservation = Reservation.create!(reservation_params)
```

it will create the object and save it before your condition is checked. you should do

```
     @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
```

this way it will only initialise it and not save unless your condition is met ie @check_count <= 3
and then when you do .save on it. it will be saved.

Comment: Right answer. :)
I have forgot about the "new"method -.- Really thanks for help :)